# maximising function subject to the constraint without using lagrange multiplier and other calculus techqniques

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, logarithms, maxima-minima

**question:**

maximise the following function $f$

$$f= x^p y^q z^r$$  subject to the constraint

$$ax+by+cz=p+q+r$$

i know how to do it using lagrange method of multipliers .

but i'm looking for an answer which **uses simple inequalities** to maximise this function

**my attempt:**
i also tried solving it using inequality but didn't get right answer

since i've to **maximise product** it will be maximum when **all three terms in sum are equal** i.e, $ax=by=cz= \dfrac{p+q+r}{3}$ then, i plug values of$ x,y,z $in terms of $a,b,c,p,q,r$ in above function$ f $ to get

$f_{max}=\dfrac{(p+q+r)^{p+q+r}}{3^{p+q+r}a^p . b^q.c^r}$

but answer is coming $\left(\dfrac{p}{a}\right)^p$ $.\left(\dfrac{q}{b}\right)^q$$\left(\dfrac{r}{c}\right)^r$

i don't know where i did wrong

please point my mistake and give plausible answer.
thank you

Comment: You need all of $a, b, c, x, y, z$ to be positive.  Further note that a product of positive numbers *which have a constant sum* gets maximised when the numbers are equal - which is easily shown by AM-GM inequality.  However, you **cannot** ignore the constant sum part in italics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by Jensen for $\ln$ we obtain:
$$\ln{x^py^qz^r}=p\ln{x}+q\ln{y}+r\ln{z}=$$
$$=p\ln{p}+q\ln{q}+r\ln{r}-p\ln{a}-q\ln{b}-r\ln{c}+p\ln\frac{ax}{p}+q\ln\frac{by}{q}+r\ln\frac{cz}{r}=$$
$$=\ln{\frac{p^pq^qr^r}{a^pb^qc^r}}+(p+q+r)\left(\frac{p}{p+q+r}\ln\frac{ax}{p}+\frac{q}{p+q+r}\ln\frac{by}{q}+\frac{r}{p+q+r}\ln\frac{cz}{r}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\ln{\frac{p^pq^qr^r}{a^pb^qc^r}}+(p+q+r)\ln\frac{ax+by+cz}{p+q+r}=\ln{\frac{p^pq^qr^r}{a^pb^qc^r}}.$$
Easy to see that the equality occurs, which says that we got a maximal value:
$$\left(\dfrac{p}{a}\right)^p\left(\dfrac{q}{b}\right)^q\left(\dfrac{r}{c}\right)^r$$